# rsync without deleting between 2 folders

Tags: 14.04, command-line, rsync

i'm looking for a command that can sync dir1 and dir2, without swapping and deleting the files in those directories.

The current command i'm using is

```
rsync -av --delete dir1 dir2
```

which deletes files that belong to dir2 but not dir1. In other words, it will create a duplicate dir1 in a fast way.

say, for example, i add 5 files to dir2 and would like to preserve the order of the command rsync. i want to sync it back to dir1. what options of rsync are available that can help me doing this?

assume i don't want to delete any files in both directories.

Comment: Try `unison` – a file-synchronization tool for Unix.

Comment: @A.B. : I have, it seems a little confusing but it's a good package. thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you this command

```
if [ -n "$(rsync -anv --delete dir1/ dir2/ | grep deleting)" ]; then \
    rsync -av dir2/ dir1/; else rsync -av dir1/ dir2/; fi
```